# DC Offset in LCD clock signal

Tags: clock, lcd, dc-offset

I am getting DC offset in clock signal. Clock signal has 24MHz frequency. The DC offset is around 400mV. Also I was expecting Square shape waveform but I am getting sinusoidal with DC offset.
Clock is generated by processor. The LCD display is working fine but I think it may impact performance of LCD display in noisy environment
Can anybody help me with possible reason for DC offset in clock signal and how to remove this offset.

Comment: You might be measuring it incorrectly and get incorrect results. How are you measuring it and with what settings?

Comment: Not using any specific setting from scope but making sure the loop created for measuring clock is small. Is there any specific requirement or setting required?
On the same board I also have sdcard clock which is being measured with same setting but didnt get any DC offset

Comment: So what type of clock signal it is? Is it square wave CMOS 3.3V or are you measuring differential LVDS or what clock? What scope settings you are using, any bandwidth limiting turned on or off? What probes you are using 10x or 1x probes, settable, which setting? What is the scope and probe bandwidth? What was the good looking SD clock frequency?